# autocomplete and footer at the bottom

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery autocomplete with the bottom of the page before footer.
I would like to know how to dynamically set the footer at the bottom as the autocomplete results list increases or decreases.

```
html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the body to 100% height aswell since the #footer is a child of body.
Currently your Body is only the height it needs to be which is 60px which #footer expands to.

Comment: not work, stay at the same place when increase the list of autocomplete